# R: cut dataframe by range of values in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=400, min=1, max=100), nrow=100))
names(data) <- c('x', 'y', 'endX', 'endY')
```

So I would like to cut it like that.

```
data$xbin <- cut(data$x, breaks = c(0, 17, 50, 66, 83, 100),include.lowest=TRUE)
data$ybin <- cut(data$y, breaks = c(0, 21.1, 36.8, 63.2, 78.9, 100),include.lowest=TRUE)
data$endXbin <- cut(data$endX, breaks = c(0, 21.1, 36.8, 63.2, 78.9, 100), include.lowest=TRUE)
data$endYbin <- cut(data$endY, breaks = c(0, 21.1, 36.8, 63.2, 78.9, 100), include.lowest=TRUE)
```

But I'm not fully satisfied with result because I want to more complicated cut. For example, I want to cut "y" only with brakes c(0, 36.8, 63,2, 100) when "x" is between 0 and 17. Also I want the same when x is between 83 and 100.

Is there elegant way to do that?

Ultimately the goal is to bin the x and y co-ordinates of passes in a football game, similar to the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: There's a conceptual problem with this. You are going to end up with y having bins of [0, 21.1], [21.1, 36.8] and [0, 36.8]. In other words, you are going to have y bins that cannot be well-ordered. This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you perhaps add some context to show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AllanCameron It is a football passes during the game (actually I have four columns: x,  y, endX, endY). And I need to cut a football pitch to achieve something like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakeyk11/football-data-analytics/main/data_directory/misc_data/images/example-4-2-1.png

I don't want to plot all passes because it will be a mess, so I need to cut the dataframe for grouping and find more frequent patterns. 

x,  y, endX, endY - are coordinates on the pitch.

Comment: In that case, you have a limited number of rectangles on the pitch, and you don't need seperate x and y bins. You could calculate a start rectangle and end rectangle for each pass. This could then be used to plot, etc. I don't think using `cut` on its own is the right way to do this. Do you have a chunk of sample data you could add to your question so we can come up with a useful answer?

Comment: @AllanCameron sure, I've added some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem seems to be assigning points in x, y co-ordinates into pre-determined regions. There are a number of ways to tackle this in R, but in any case we will need to define the co-ordinates of the different regions of the football pitch:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

pitch_df <- data.frame(xmin = c(rep(0, 3), rep(17, 5), rep(50, 5), 
                                rep(66, 5), rep(83, 3)),
                       xmax = c(rep(17, 3), rep(50, 5), rep(66, 5),
                                rep(83, 5), rep(100, 3)),
                       ymin = c(0, 21.1, 78.9, 
                                rep(c(0, 21.1, 36.8, 63.2, 78.9), 3),
                                0, 21.1, 78.9),
                       ymax = c(21.1, 78.9, 100, 
                                rep(c(21.1, 36.8, 63.2, 78.9, 100), 3),
                                21.1, 78.9, 100),
                       segment = LETTERS[1:21])

pitch_df$xmid <- (pitch_df$xmax + pitch_df$xmin)/2
pitch_df$ymid <- (pitch_df$ymax + pitch_df$ymin)/2
```

This gives us a data frame describing all of the rectangles making up the pitch and their associated centroids:

```r
pitch_df
#>    xmin xmax ymin  ymax segment xmid  ymid
#> 1     0   17  0.0  21.1       A  8.5 10.55
#> 2     0   17 21.1  78.9       B  8.5 50.00
#> 3     0   17 78.9 100.0       C  8.5 89.45
#> 4    17   50  0.0  21.1       D 33.5 10.55
#> 5    17   50 21.1  36.8       E 33.5 28.95
#> 6    17   50 36.8  63.2       F 33.5 50.00
#> 7    17   50 63.2  78.9       G 33.5 71.05
#> 8    17   50 78.9 100.0       H 33.5 89.45
#> 9    50   66  0.0  21.1       I 58.0 10.55
#> 10   50   66 21.1  36.8       J 58.0 28.95
#> 11   50   66 36.8  63.2       K 58.0 50.00
#> 12   50   66 63.2  78.9       L 58.0 71.05
#> 13   50   66 78.9 100.0       M 58.0 89.45
#> 14   66   83  0.0  21.1       N 74.5 10.55
#> 15   66   83 21.1  36.8       O 74.5 28.95
#> 16   66   83 36.8  63.2       P 74.5 50.00
#> 17   66   83 63.2  78.9       Q 74.5 71.05
#> 18   66   83 78.9 100.0       R 74.5 89.45
#> 19   83  100  0.0  21.1       S 91.5 10.55
#> 20   83  100 21.1  78.9       T 91.5 50.00
#> 21   83  100 78.9 100.0       U 91.5 89.45
```

To make sure this is what we wanted, let's draw the pitch to ensure the areas are as expected:

```r
ggplot(pitch_df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
            fill = 'green', color = 'yellow', linewidth = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50, color = 'white', linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = xmid, y = ymid, label = segment)) +
  coord_flip(expand = FALSE) +
  labs(x = 'x', y = 'y') +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5)
```

[image]

Now let's take some reproducible fake data that represents the passes around the pitch:

```r
set.seed(1)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=400, min=1, max=100), nrow=100))
names(data) <- c('x', 'y', 'endX', 'endY')
```

What we need to do now is use our pitch data to get our pass data into start and end segments, then to count how many passes were made between given segments:

```r
passes <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    segment = with(pitch_df, segment[x >= xmin & x < xmax & y >= ymin & y < ymax]),
    end_segment = with(pitch_df, segment[endX >= xmin & endX < xmax &
                                           endY >= ymin & endY < ymax])) %>%
  count(segment, end_segment) %>%
  arrange(-n) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This gives us:

```r
passes
#> # A tibble: 82 x 3
#>    segment end_segment     n
#>    <chr>   <chr>       <int>
#>  1 F       H               6
#>  2 B       H               3
#>  3 F       E               3
#>  4 U       F               3
#>  5 D       B               2
#>  6 E       B               2
#>  7 F       T               2
#>  8 G       A               2
#>  9 P       P               2
#> 10 Q       H               2
#> # ... with 72 more rows
```

Now we can perform left joins with the pitch data frame to get the x, y co-ordinates of the segment-wise passes. We will filter out those cases with only a single pass to make the resulting plot look less chaotic:

```r
pass_df <- left_join(passes, pitch_df, by = 'segment') %>%
  select(!xmin:ymax) %>%
  rename(x = xmid, y = ymid) %>%
  left_join(pitch_df, by = c(end_segment = 'segment')) %>%
  select(!xmin:ymax) %>%
  rename(xend = xmid, yend = ymid) %>%
  filter(n > 1)
```

That gives

```r
pass_df
#> # A tibble: 11 x 7
#>    segment end_segment     n     x     y  xend  yend
#>    <chr>   <chr>       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 F       H               6  33.5  50    33.5  89.4
#>  2 B       H               3   8.5  50    33.5  89.4
#>  3 F       E               3  33.5  50    33.5  29.0
#>  4 U       F               3  91.5  89.4  33.5  50  
#>  5 D       B               2  33.5  10.6   8.5  50  
#>  6 E       B               2  33.5  29.0   8.5  50  
#>  7 F       T               2  33.5  50    91.5  50  
#>  8 G       A               2  33.5  71.1   8.5  10.6
#>  9 P       P               2  74.5  50    74.5  50  
#> 10 Q       H               2  74.5  71.1  33.5  89.4
#> 11 T       E               2  91.5  50    33.5  29.0
```

This is all the information we need to replicate the diagram in the example image:

```
ggplot(pitch_df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
            fill = 'gray20', color = 'gray50', linewidth = 0.3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 50, color = 'white') +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, color = n), data = pass_df, size = 4) +
  geom_link(aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, size = after_stat(-index),
                color = n),
            data = pass_df, alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate('point', 50, 50, size = 34, shape = 21, color = 'white', fill = NA) +
  coord_flip(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'orangered', guide = 'none') +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 4), guide = 'none') +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5,
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'gray20', color = NA))
```

[image]

Of course, for completeness you might want to add annotations representing the penalty box and a nice legend, but these are deatils that I won't add to what is already a long answer.
<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Allan thanks for detailed and helpful answer.